# Append JSON Strings

Tags: jquery, json, string, append, concatenation

I'm having a little trouble with some JS and hope someone can help.

I have two JSON strings that are collected via AJAX using jQuery and then parsed accordingly. The issue I have is that if I ever want to add new features to the application I am making, the JSON strings are statically stored in the database and don't change if new attributes are added to the default JSON string.

```
var string1 = {
    "col1": [
        {
            "foo": "bar"
        }
    ],
    "col2": [
        {
            "foo": "bar",
            "bar": "foo"
        }
    ],
    "col3": [
        {
            "foo": "bar"
        }
    ]
}

var string2 = {
    "col1": [
        {
            "foo": "bar"
        }
    ],
    "col2": [
        {
            "foo": "bar"
        }
    ]
}
```

`string2` is the user saved the script, hypothetically saved three days ago. Since then, the default string `string1` has been added to, and the information needs to be added to `string2`.

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: @3nigma It could be a type `]}` for `col2` and `col3` should be `}]`

Comment: Excuse the typos, it's a bit late!

Comment: Yeah.. timezones make world more interesting...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### This will do:

```js
// Input:
var json_string = '{"name":"John"}';

// Convert JSON array to JavaScript object
var json_obj = JSON.parse( json_string );

// Add new key value pair "myData": "Helo World" to object
json_obj.myData = 'Hello World';

// Another more dynamic way to add new key/value pair
json_obj['myAnotherData'] = 'FooBar';

// Convert back to JSON string
json_string = JSON.stringify( json_obj );

// Log to console:
console.log( json_string );
```

#### Output:

```json
{
    "name": "John",
    "myData": "Hello World",
    "myAnotherData": "FooBar"
}
```

#### jQuery JSON parser:

If you want to use jQuery parser or need support for IE7 you can replace

```js
var json_obj = JSON.parse( json_string );
```

with

```js
var json_obj = $.parseJSON( json_string );
```

Unfortunately, jQuery cannot convert `json_object` back to JSON string, you will need another plugin or library for that.

#### More on topic:

[MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JSON)

[Browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=JSON)

Comment: `$.parseJSON( json_string );` can be `JSON.parse( json_string );` too.

Comment: JSON.stringify( json_obj ) will turn it back into a string and works in all modern browsers http://caniuse.com/#search=json.stringify

Answer (score 1):

use back slash:

"{\"id\": \"abc123\", \"success\": true}"

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but this should work:

```
function updateJsonString(oldString, newString) {
    var oldObj = JSON.parse(oldString), newObj = newString.parse(newString);
    for(prop in newObj) {
        if(newObj.hasOwnProp(prop)) {
            if(!oldObj.hasOwnProp(prop)) {
                oldObj[prop] = newObj[prop];
            }
        }
    }

    return JSON.stringify(oldObj);
}

var updatedString = updateJsonString(string2, string1);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll test it tomorrow, it's getting late.. hence the typos and what not! Much appreciated..